# Microsoft Unity Dependency Injection with WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following architecture:

- Data
  Database Layer
- WebAPI
  Presentation Layer
- Resolver
  IoC Register Layer
- Services
  Business Layer

In WebApiConfig.cs(App_Start) i register the unity container the following way:

```
// Unity Container Resolver
var container = new UnityContainer();

//Registers the repository interface in Resolver(IoC Register Layer)
var UResolver = new UnityRegisterContainer();
UResolver.RegisterContainer(ref container);

//Configures WebAPI DependecyResolver to use UnityResolver
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

My Resolver(IoC Register Layer):

```
public class UnityRegisterContainer
{
   public void RegisterContainer(ref UnityContainer container)
   {
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
public static KeyService KeyLibrary{ get; set; }

// GET api/values
[Route("Keys")]
public IEnumerable<KeyDTO> Get()
{
    var Keys = KeyLibrary.GetAllKeys();

    return Keys;
}
```

KeyService:

```
public class KeyService: IService
{
    IUnitOfWork UOW { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all Keys
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<KeyDTO> GetAllKeys()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Key>, IEnumerable<KeyDTO>>(UOW.Keys.GetAllKeys());
    }
}
```

IService

```
public interface IService
{
}
```

IUnitOfWork

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IKeyRepository Keys { get; }
    int Complete();
}
```

How can i inject the class libraries and repositories with unity?

Comment: you can use constructor injection

Comment: Looking at `RegisterContainer`, I think the overload you are after is [IUnityContainer.RegisterType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650520.aspx). So you can call it like this: `container.RegisterType<IKeyService, KeyService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());`. That is, you will need an `IKeyService` interface and you'll have to point it to the concrete implementation (if you want to make your mocking/testing life easier)

Comment: Just curious. Why is your `UnityContainer` passed in parameter as a `ref`? I'm not too familiar with the Unit library. Is the container a `struct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use constructor injection and let the `DependencyResolver` do it job and pass the necessary dependencies to the classes.

```
public class KeyController : ApiController {
    IKeyService keyService;    
    public KeyController(IKeyService keyService) {
        this.keyService = keyService
    }

    // GET api/values
    [Route("Keys")]
    public IEnumerable<KeyDTO> Get() {
        var Keys = keyService.GetAllKeys();        
        return Keys;
    }
}

public interface IKeyService : IService {
    IEnumerable<KeyDTO> GetAllKeys();
}

public class KeyService: IKeyService {
    IUnitOfWork UOW;

    public KeyService(IUnitOfWork uow) {
        this.UOW = uow
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all Keys
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<KeyDTO> GetAllKeys() {
        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Key>, IEnumerable<KeyDTO>>(UOW.Keys.GetAllKeys());
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork {
    public UnitOfWork(IKeyRepository repository) {
        Keys = repository;
    }
    IKeyRepository Keys { get;private set }
    public int Complete(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though constructor injection is preferred (and property injection is sometimes not recommended), you can also use the `[Dependency]` attribute in implementation classes that have dependencies, like this:

```
public class KeyService: IService
{
    // Public setter, private getter, so you can mock and manually assing in Unit Tests
    [Dependency]
    public IUnitOfWork UOW { private get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<KeyDTO> GetAllKeys()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Key>, IEnumerable<KeyDTO>>(UOW.Keys.GetAllKeys());
    }
}
```

See [Annotating Objects for Property Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx)

Comment: As you said, property injection is not recommended for many reasons. You don't exactly know when the properties are going to be injected, you won't have access to them in the constructor (if you ever need them), and it pollutes your code with an attribute, meaning that your code is now tied to this library. It may be cool for a few stuff (like a logger for instance), but as @robinet said, you should prefer constructor injection.

Comment: Unless you have a `TaxStrategyFactory` that depends on 10+ `ITaxCalculationStrategy` and your only entry points to any of the `ITaxCalculationStrategy` are a handful of methods that don't require constructor initialization (except for dependency resolution, maybe). I would rather have 10+ injected properties in the factory (which will only be a dispatcher in the end) than 10+ parameters in the constructor. Tax calculation is probably not the best example, but I've come across issues like this

Comment: In this case, I would probably give the `TaxStrategyFactory` an instance of the resolver. This way, you dependency resolution is handled at a clear level, not everywhere. My main concern about the property injection is at the attribute level to be honest. This ties possible a lot of your code to a library and makes it possible for it to break you, especially when you upgrade. You might find this reading from Uncle Bob interesting: https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/blogs-by-robert-martin/dependency-injection-inversion

Comment: Agreed, with the `[Dependency]` attribute (or the `[Inject]` attribute for that matter), you are back again depending on a concrete implementation, a DI container implementation, whether it's Unity, NInject or whathaveyou